# Using vba to login

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use vba to login to a site. This makes it easy for everyone and not everyone has to know the password this way.
However, the site was recently updated and now the code that I used (that was duct taped together from bits and pieces)

```
`Sub apiweb()
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://apiweb.biomerieux.com/login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True
Do
 ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.login.Value = "xxxx"
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "yyyy"
' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub`
```

So it used to work that you press a button in excel, the site would open and after a second or 2 the login and password would show up and you'd just press login. Now it only opens the site.

I tried a few things including inspecting the elements, but i'm a novice so I don't really know what to look for or what to do. So any help (and explanation) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this method?

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://apiweb.biomerieux.com/login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.signupEmail.Value = "signupEmail"
HTMLDoc.all.signupPassword.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("signupSubmit")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

As an aside, hit F12 to see the HTML behind your browser.

Comment: unfortunately, nope. It runs into the same problem as the first solution.
The sites gives an error that the login field is mandatory to fill in. Even though it is filled in by the macro.
The site doesn't seem to recognize it.
And if I remove 1 letter and replace it, it works fine for the login field but then it gives the same message for the password field. And again, that can be fixed with the same solution, but that defeats the purpose.
But I must say, I have learned quite a bit so far, so it's not for nothing!

Comment: Sorry, still nope. At first the code jumped to the debug section after the browser.timeout=60 part. But I fixed that by making it 6.
After that it opened the site, and filled in everything and then nothing. I saw you added code to make it press the go button automatically, but that doesn't seem to be working. And still the same 'login field mandatory' error when I manually press the 'go' button.
If I can help in any other way, id be glad to, just tell me how :)

Comment: I don't have login creds for that site.  When I tested the code I hit F8, over and over and over, to step through the logic, line by line.  The signupEmail.Value and signupPassword.Value variables were both filled un and the button was clicked.  That's as far as I got.  Again, I don't have an account to login to.  Double-check that your username and password are correct, make sure there are no spaces at the end, or something weird like that, and clear the cache in the browser.  That's about all I can think of.  If you have access to a different machine, you should try that as well.

Comment: Is there a way to pm you the login info? I'd rather not post it here for everyone to see. Maybe that would help.

Comment: rms 7272 at gmail com
Remove the spaces and change the at to @

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub WbClkMe()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://apiweb.biomerieux.com/login"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signupEmail") ' This is based on on your website

HTMLInput.Value = "" 'Put the value of Usernamae

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signupPassword") 'This is based on on your website

HTMLInput.Value = "" 'Put the value of Password

Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signupSubmit") 'This is based on on your website

HTMLButton.Click


End Sub
```

Comment: This code only works in Internet Explorer

Before you run this code, follow below instructions

1. Change the value of Username and Password in the VBA code
2. Activate **Microsoft Internet Control** and **Microsoft HTML Object Library** **(Tools>>References)*

Comment: Alright, this works, sort of. While it does indeed input the username and password and click on the 'go' button, the site gives an error message that a username has to be filled in.
By simply removing 1 letter and retyping it, it fixes it. However, this kind of defeats the purpose of the macro. The same goes for the password.